# Coordinating multiple Javascript files to load in order after window.onload = function()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found that when I added media content to my HTML5 program, things don't work properly unless I run the scripts inside of a 
    window.onload = function () {
    }

The problem is that, even though my scripts are included in the order I want them to run, if I wrap each script inside of a window.onload = function(), I get errors that look like they are not running in order.

In my .html file:

```
<script src="1.js"></script>
<script src="2.js"></script>
<script src="3.js"></script>
```

Is there a correct way to tell all my scripts to run after window.onload so that things are loaded in order and I don't have issues with functions and variables not having been declared, even though I want to split my project up until multiple .js files to make it more manageable?

I put this declaration under window.onload because if I tried to declare bgm "audio1" before window.onload, it kept behaving like the resource didn't exist.

```
var Foo = {
choice: ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
bgm: document.getElementById("audio1"),
song1: "test.mp3"
};
```

Nothing 'runs' before window.onload. Infact, all my executing functions are under that one. But I tried to declare other functions in other files with or without wrapping that .js file in a window.onload = function() {} but it was giving me errors.

I'm getting an "Uncaught ReferenceError: Foo is not defined"

This happens when I declare Foo in the last executed .js file, and it is in that window.onload wrapper.

The scripts before have functions (that are just functions, they don't get called until the last .js script which is all wrapped in window.onload) which look for that Foo variable.

If I put Foo in that file, it can't find the document.getElementById("audio1") because, I think, it hasn't been loaded yet. And if I put it back here, it finds the audio1 but the other functions that are declared can't use the variable. The only solution I've found is mashing the entire javascript application together into one file all under window.onload function.

I tried wrapping the other .js functions inside of window.onload functions of their own but then I get an error that the functions declared in those earlier scripts are not defined.

3.js

```
window.onload = function() {

var Foo= {
    choice: ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
    bgm: document.getElementById("audio1"),
    };

Game.NewArea("newgame");
}
```

2.js

```
var Game = (function() {
function NewArea($area) {
        switch($area)
    {
    case "newgame": 
        $("#textbox").html("Test");
        $("#choice0").html("Look");
        Foo.choice[0] = "look_1";
        Foo.bgm.play();
        break;

        default: break;
        }
    }
    return {
        NewArea: NewArea
    };
})();
```

Comment: `window.onload = function() { function1(); function2(); function3() }`

Comment: The key is that your code shouldn't be doing anything until `window.onload`, at which point the files have all loaded. The fact that they're running as soon as they're included indicates a larger problem with how you've structured your code.

Comment: I agree with this, but the problem remains.

Comment: I expanded on the question to try to describe the problem a little more clearly.

Comment: Did the answer below help you to solve your problem?

Answer (score -2):

Can't you just define a plain function in each of the three JS files and then add fourth file / script section that calls them on window load in the correct order?

```
<script src="1.js"></script>
<script src="2.js"></script>
<script src="3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload(function() {
    one(); //Function from 1.js
    two(); //Function from 2.js
    three(); //Function from 3.js
    four(); //Function from 4.js
})
</script>
```

Note that the JS files should not use `window.onload` but instead just define the functions mentioned in the code example.

Comment: You might want to add an example to this -- in its current state this is more of a comment.